# How to repeat proof tactics in case in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I would like to extend the exercise 6.10 in Coq'Art by adding a theorem that forall months which are not January, is_January will equal false.

My definition of months looks like this:

```
 Inductive month : Set :=
   | January : month
   | February : month
   | March : month
   | April : month
   | May : month
   | June : month
   | July : month
   | August : month
   | September : month
   | October : month
   | November : month
   | December : month
  .

Check month_rect.
```

My definition of is_January looks like this:

```
Definition is_January (m : month) : Prop :=
  match m with
  | January => True
  | other   => False
  end.
```

I am doing the following to test that it is correct.

```
Eval compute in (is_January January).
Eval compute in (is_January December).

Theorem is_January_eq_January :
  forall m : month, m = January -> is_January m = True.
Proof.
  intros m H.
  rewrite H.
  compute; reflexivity.
Qed.
```

I am not very happy with this theorem's proof.

```
Theorem is_January_neq_not_January :
  forall m : month, m <> January -> is_January m = False.
Proof.
  induction m.
  - contradiction.
  - intro H; simpl; reflexivity.
  - intro H; simpl; reflexivity.
  - intro H; simpl; reflexivity.
  - intro H; simpl; reflexivity.
  - intro H; simpl; reflexivity.
  - intro H; simpl; reflexivity.
  - intro H; simpl; reflexivity.
  - intro H; simpl; reflexivity.
  - intro H; simpl; reflexivity.
  - intro H; simpl; reflexivity.
  - intro H; simpl; reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Is there anyway in Coq to repeat the `- intro H; simpl; reflexivity.` case proof for non-January months (so I would only have two - or something similar so I do not have to repeat myself)?  Or am I just completely going about this proof the wrong way?

Comment: You probably want your `is_January` function to return `bool`, not `Prop`. `Prop` is a type of logical propositions (there are plenty of them), so it's not supposed to be used as a usual boolean-like type with only *two* values (`true` and `false`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do this is to

```
Theorem is_January_neq_not_January :
  forall m : month, m <> January -> is_January m = False.
Proof.
  induction m; try reflexivity.
  contradiction.
Qed.
```

- `simpl` is implicit in `reflexivity` and hence unnecessary.
- `t1 ; t2` applies tactic `t2` to all branches created by the application
  of tactic `t1`.
- `try t` tries to apply tactic `t` (as the name implies) or does nothing
  if `t` fails.

What this does is run `induction` as before and then immediately run `reflexivity` on all branches (which works on & solves all but the January branch).  After that, you're left with that single branch, which can be solved by `contradiction` as before.

Other potentially useful constructions for more complex situations are

- `(t1 ; t2)` which groups tactics `t1` and `t2`,
- `t1 | t2`, `t1 || t2`, `t1 + t2` which are variations on "try `t1` and if
  that fails / doesn't do anything useful / …, do `t2` instead,
- `fail` which explicitly fails (this is useful if you want to un-do/reset
  what happened in a branch)

  (As a complex example from one of my proofs, consider `try (split; unfold not; intro H'; inversion H'; fail)`.  This attempts to create several sub-branches (`split`) hoping that they're all contradictory and can be solved by `inversion H'`.  If that doesn't work, the `inversion`s would just create a big mess, so it explicitly `fail`s in order to un-do the effects of the tactic chain.  End result is that many boring cases get solved automatically and the interesting ones remain unchanged for manual solving.)
- and many more – look at [Chapter 9 of the Coq Reference Manual ("The tactic language")](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual011.html) for longer descriptions of these and many other useful constructions.

Comment: `now destruct m.` will do the trick as well -- it's equivalent to `destruct m; easy.` and the [`easy`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Tactics.html) tactic is clever enough to use `contradiction` and `reflexivity`.